# VBA: Query an array with headers using SQL

Tags: sql, vba, odbc

I know the potential to query a csv file exists using odbc (See: [here](http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=5250)), but what about an array in memory?

For example, imagine an array with the following structure:

```
tbl = [[Dog,Cat,Bird];[1,7,10]]

sql = "select Dog from tbl;"

result = 1
```

Is this possible? Do I need to write my array to a csv, then re-read the data?

This would be a little painful and circuitous but simple enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That just could be done with `Linq to Objects`, I think that it's not possible to query against a memory datasource with ODBC.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in Excel, you can use HLOOKUP (or VLOOKUP)

```
Sub QueryArray()

    Dim arr(1 To 3, 1 To 3) As Variant

    arr(1, 1) = "Dog"
    arr(1, 2) = "Cat"
    arr(1, 3) = "Bird"
    arr(2, 1) = 1
    arr(2, 2) = 7
    arr(2, 3) = 10

    Debug.Print Application.WorksheetFunction.HLookup("Cat", arr, 2, False)

End Sub
```

If you're not in Excel, you could set a reference to Excel.  Don't discount just looping through the array either.  I'm sure you have a lot of elements, but writing a CSV and then ODBC'ing has to have some overhead and it's possible that looping would be faster even with a large array.

Comment: thanks but with this it becomes quite complex (annoying) to do aggregation, grouping, etc.

Comment: Yeah, good point.  If you want simple stuff like lookups and single variable aggregation, it might work.  But if you need all the power of SQL, then nothing else will do.